# Is passing the same entity to arguments with different intent undefined behavior?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

```
module foo
contains
   subroutine bar()
      integer :: i(3)

      i(1) = 1
      i(2) = 2
      i(3) = 3
      call baz(i, i)
   end subroutine

   subroutine baz(a,b)
      integer, intent(in) :: a(:)
      integer, intent(inout) :: b(:)

      b(2) = 5
      print *, a
      print *, b
   end subroutine

end module
program xx
   use foo
   call bar()
end program
```

In this code, I am passing the same array `i` to baz, binding it to arguments having different intent. Of course, when I print `a`, it changes. Is this undefined behavior, or it is according to specification ?

Note that I fully expect this to happen. I am not puzzled by the behavior, I just want to understand if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 4):

It is undefined behavior. Fortran generally prohibits argument aliasing (i.e. several arguments pointing to the same actual data), unless the arguments have the POINTER or TARGET attributes.

Comment: Technically, the compiler should be able to catch this and forbid it, why isn't so ?

Comment: @StefanoBorini: 1) Compiler developers not having an infinite amount of time. 2) IIRC aliasing might be allowed for arguments which are not written to, or anyway is widely used and so must be supported. 3) Difficulty of checking non-trivial cases and not introducing false positives (see (2)).

Comment: This is not so easy. Problem arises only in certain situations, i.e. when one changes the arguments. One should read the standard. It is totally OK, if both are `intent(IN)`. The same holds if on of the arguments is passed by `VALUE`.

Comment: There is a difference between what is illegal and what illegal situations a compiler is required to detect.   Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223314/enforce-intentin-declared-variables-in-fortran-as-constant-also-in-called-subr/7223629