# How to force compiler to interpret omitted intent as intent(inout)

Tags: fortran

This question is connected to the problem: how to detect violation of `intent(in)` inside subprograms. But I haven't found the answer in the related question [Enforce intent(in) declared variables in Fortran as constant also in called subroutines/functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223314/enforce-intentin-declared-variables-in-fortran-as-constant-also-in-called-subr).

A variable which is declared as `intent(in)` can be modified by another subprogram/function with omitted intent declaration.

For example:

```
module test
  implicit none
  contains

  subroutine fun1(x)
    real(8), intent(in)::x
    call fun2(x)
  end subroutine

  subroutine fun2(x)
    real(8) :: x
    x = 10
  end subroutine
end module
```

This code can be compiled without any errors/warnings by gfortran and ifort.  So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to forbid omitting intent declaration?
2. Is it possible to force a Fortran compiler to interpret omitted intent as `intent(inout)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both answers are NO. Unspecified intent is fundamentally different from all other intents. It is different from intent(inout), because you can pass a nondefinable expression to a subroutine with unspecified intent.

Also in many contexts it is not allowed to specify intent at all (procedure arguments, pointers in Fortran 95,...)

If you want to require specifying of intent, you may define your subroutine as `pure` but it does much more than that. But it may be the right thing for you. It forbids any side-effects.

Comment: So it means that there is no way to be sure that intent(in) will not be violated for not "pure" subroutines?  Thanks by the way for "pure" hint.

Comment: Unfortunately the calling procedure cannot look inside other procedures. It can even see its interface, e.g., the declared intent.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should get a compile error due to the automatically defined interface. I would expect the same with a wrong dimension for example (I switched the fun2 dummy argument x to z that I think demonstrates more clearly my point).

```
module test
  implicit none
  contains

  subroutine fun1(x)
    real(8), intent(in)::x
    call fun2(x)
  end subroutine

  subroutine fun2(z)
    real(3) :: z
    z = 10
  end subroutine
end module
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense in the slightest.  There is no "automatically defined interface"; changing the name of the dummy argument has no effect at all; it seems to confuse the idea of kind with dimension.